# How to make a blur thumbnail image for a video in ios

Tags: ios, video-thumbnails

I am trying to make an app in ios as it will show video or image first with the thumbnail.When the user click on that thumbnail the video or image will be shown.How can i achieve that?Can anyone suggest something to implement such thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) for the blur effect. You should provide more info about your images/videos.